# How to make a better findGoodMax function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function which I use to find a good max value for gauges.

```
function findGoodMax(x) {
  var y = Math.pow(10, x.toString().length - 1);
  x = (x/y);
  x = Math.ceil(x);
  x = x*y;
  return x || 10;
}

findGoodMax(33)   //=> 40
findGoodMax(76)   //=> 80
findGoodMax(543)  //=> 600
findGoodMax(1734) //=> 2000
```

The problem is:

```
findGoodMax(0.1)      //=> 100
findGoodMax(0.00001)  //=> 1000000
```

How can I modify my function to handle decimals?

Also, I would like

```
if (x > 10 && x < 100) {
  x = 100;
}
```

And the same for other numbers of decimal places, basically it should round to the nearest power of 10.

Handling negative numbers would be great also, so -0.1 would output 0, -0.01 would output -0.1, at least I think that makes sense.

Comment: What should you get for an input of `0.1`?

Comment: @VivinPaliath 1 i think makes sense

Comment: What about `0.01`? Should that be `0.1`? How about `0.025`? Would that also be `0.1`?

Comment: Oh, and it should be able to handle negative numbers, so an input of -0.1 should output 0

Comment: @VivinPaliath yes, thats the idea

Comment: You said that it should round to the "nearest power of 10", but you have `findGoodMax(33)` returning `40`, which is not a power of 10. Did you mean nearest multiple of 10? Also `-0.1` returning `0` does not make sense either since it is not a power of 10.

Comment: @VivinPaliath no, i meant power of ten, i dont like how it currently functions. 33 should output 100

Comment: Shouldn't `-0.1` remain `-0.1` since that is `-10^(-1)`?

Comment: @VivinPaliath I could go either way on that, but i think i would prefer -0.1 outputting 0 because the output should always be greater than the input

Comment: Sounds like you need to take the logarithm base 10 of your input, round up, then exponentiate 10 to that value.  That's the non-hacky way to do it instead of relying on the length of the string representation.

Comment: Then you need to define your function better because it is not consistent. `-0.1` should remain `-0.1` if your function always gives you the nearest power of 10. `0.1` should also remain `0.1`. If you have `0.25`, then the answer would still be `0.1` since that is the closest power of 10.

Comment: @VivinPaliath It gives you the nearest power of 10 that is greater than the input.

Comment: Ok then for `-0.1` it should return `1` because `0` is not a power of `10`. `0` is not a power of any number (`log(0)` is undefined).

Comment: @VivinPaliath okay, thats fine.

Comment: The reason I mention is that the more consistent your function is, the easier it is to debug/maintain. The more special cases you have (especially ones that contradict your function's definition), the more difficult it is to maintain and debug. :)

Comment: @VivinPaliath valid points, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSkss/5/)?

```
var findGoodMax = function(num){
    var s = num.toExponential().split('e');    
    //console.log(s);
    var pow = parseInt(s[1]);
    var isNegative = s[0][0] === "-";
    if (isNegative) {                
        if (pow === 0 || pow === -1) {
            return 0;
        } else if (pow < 0) {
            pow += 1;
        }
        return -Math.pow(10, pow);
    } else {
        return Math.pow(10, pow + 1);
    }
}

test output: 

33 : 100 
76 : 100 
543 : 1000 
1734 : 10000 
-543 : -100 
-1734 : -1000 
-0.00001 : -0.0001 
0.00001 : 0.0001 
-0.1 : 0 
0 : 10 
1 : 10 
5 : 10 
-5 : 0 
-33 : -10
```

Comment: I kindof wanted 0.00001 to output 0.0001, not 0

Comment: This is close, but `findGoodMax(0.00001)` seems to be returning `0.0001` when it should return `0.00001` (the input is already a power of 10).

Comment: Agreed, but op says that 0.00001 should output 0.0001

Comment: I think that's a typo :). @sherlock, can you confirm?

Comment: I would prefer that the output is always greater than the input.

Comment: > or >= ? Greater strictly or not?

Comment: Then I guess the -0.00001 has I problem. I'll look into it and edit.

Comment: Ah, so the definition of your function is "the nearest power of 10 other than the number itself, if it is already a power of 10". `findGoodMax(-0.00001)` violates that it seems, because shouldn't you get `0.0001`?

Comment: +1: This is close enough and pax162 is already attempting to fix the one disparity.

Comment: Ok, edited again. Try playing with the fiddle and let me know if you get any more bad results.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this question and I thought I'd take a crack at it. First attempt - I think this works, but it might be broken (and I don't think it handles nonintegers at the moment, will fix that).

```
function findGoodMax(x) {
  if (x < 0) return 0; // Negative numbers.
  if (x < 1) return 1; // Decimals between 0 and 1.

  var i = 1;

  while (x % (10 ^ i)) {
    i++;
  }

  var y = Math.pow(10, i);
  x = (x/y);
  x = Math.ceil(x);
  x = x*y;
  return x || 10;
}
```